# How do I get user input validation into my java calculator program?

Tags: java, validation, intellij-idea

So, I recently made a calculator in java as homework and I've gotten all the ways I can make it, down to a tee. I've done `if` statements and `switch` statements to allow the user to get different answers depending on which operator they used `(/, *, +, -)`, however, I don't quite fully understand `for`, `do` and `do-while` loops yet to integrate it into my program.

This is my Calculator's source code. As you can see the switch statement prints "Invalid" if it's not an operator, however, I don't want the user to have to rerun the whole app, I want it to loop (and not for just the operator, but for the numbers as well)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JCal
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double num1, num2, divided, multiplied, added, subtracted;
    char operator;

    System.out.print("Value A: ");
    num1 = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Operator (/, *, +, -): ");
    operator = input.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.print("Value B: ");
    num2 = input.nextDouble();

    divided = num1 / num2;
    multiplied = num1 * num2;
    added = num1 + num2;
    subtracted = num1 - num2;

    switch (operator)
    {
        case '/':
        {
            System.out.println("Result: " + divided);
            break;
        }
        case '*':
        {
            System.out.println("Result: " + multiplied);
            break;
        }
        case '+':
        {
            System.out.println("Result: " + added);
            break;
        }
        case '-':
        {
            System.out.println("Result: " + subtracted);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid operator!");
            break;
        }
    }
}

}
```

I tried something like:

```
double num1;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

do
        {
            System.out.println("Value A: ");
            while (! input.hasNextDouble());
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid number!");
                input.nextDouble();
            }
        } while (num1 = input.hasNextDouble());
```

That's where I get stuck, the `while (num1 = input.hasNextDouble());` is a `boolean` and a `double` clashing, according to IntelliJ (I assume because num1 is a `double` and the `.hasNext` function gives a `boolean`, they don't go together.) so  IntelliJ underlines it red.

THANK YOU SO MUCH, if you took time out of your day to help me with this probably trivial problem.

Comment: You don't have to explain your brace style. We can obviously see it in your code. And some of us will hate it, and some of us use it (I'm in the hating/not-using type, especially here, because it wastes lines making the code-blocks unnecessarily lengthier). Your explanation adds more wasted space (space not devoted to your question).

Comment: You state that you understand ``do`` statements, but there is no do-statement in java. There is, however, a ``do-while`` statement.

Comment: All java conditions need to be boolean. For example, in the while-clause, you need to have something that evaluates to true or false, not an integer.

Comment: @NomadMaker, my mistake with ```do``` statement thing (I said I didn't really understand it, I'm still in the process of learning Java). I admit the brace thing was unnecessary. Also is there really no way for a java program to recognize if a correct numerical value was placed without putting parameters down like ```while (example <= 1 && example >= 5){}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could create a 'bool Exit' variable and initially set it to False

put your entire code (except for main obviously) in a do while loop with the condition
being if until exit is true

```
main {
   do {
      ... your code
   }while(Exit != True)
}
```

So after every run at the end you can ask the user to try another calculation or not (yes/no) and if *no*, set Exit to true and your program will come out of the loop.
if *yes* set Exit to False and your program will loop again.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to make it more Java-like, e.g. `boolean`, not `bool`.

Comment: Java naming conventions have variables start with a lower case letter (exit, not Exit).

Comment: There is no True constant in java, though there is a true one.

Answer (score 1):

here is a code I wrote a few weeks ago, hope it helps you.

```
        int digits;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer value: ");
    
        while (!scan.hasNextInt()) { //While loop for input validation
            System.out.print("This is not an integer, Please enter a valid value: ");
            scan.next();
        }
        digits = scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: this is of course for Integer, modifying it for a double should be easy enough.